# Ошибка при установке JCL - отсутствует rtl220.bpl

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe8

При установке компонентов JCL, а именно при запуске Install.bat вылетает ошибка

[image]

Comment: XE8 - единственная версия delphi на компьютере? Если нет - установлены ли джедаи на предыдущие версии? Из той же папки, откуда запускается текущий инсталлятор?

Answer (score 1):

rtl220.bpl - это часть Delphi XE8 (по умолчанию ставится в C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0)

Варианты:

1. Повреждённая установка Delphi. К примеру, в реестре есть записи о IDE, но самой IDE нет (либо частично удалена). Лечится переустановкой/repair/чисткой реестра.
2. Проблемы с путями поиска. Найдите rtl220.bpl и убедитесь, что эта папка (обычно - 32-битная C:\Windows\System32) есть в переменной окружения PATH. Не забудьте перезагрузиться.